# Solution for async requests hitting database at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

So, I have multiple ajax requests that call a C# method, which among other things, checks for a value in the database and decreases it by one.

```
public SomeModel Get(int id)
     ...
     credit.Available -= 1;
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

So, in theory, each time the method is run, the credit available decreases by one. But as they are run almost in parallel, the `credit.Available` is always the same and gets decreased **only once, even though it is run 5** times, for example. If the number is like **20 times, it gets decreased like twice**.

What can be done to go around this?

Comment: Don't use an ORM for this. Consider what your code does - all 5 users read the same value, eg 10. All 5 reduce it by 1, then all 5 save the *same* value, 9. If you used a SQL command like `UPDATE ... SET AVAILABLE=AVAILABLE-1` you'd have no problem

Comment: The duplicate explains why ORMs can't make increments/decrements but this question provides an actual solution

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, go on, I'm listening

Comment: The solution was already posted by jhilden

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, but where will that code go?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using raw SQL or a SQL stored procedure to do the work.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET Balance = Balance - 1
WHERE id = @id
```

If you are using Entity Framework you can call this using the following:

```
var sql = "UPDATE tbl SET Balance = Balance - 1 WHERE id = @id";
dbContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, id);
```

Comment: Where would that code go then?

Comment: @chiapa I added a sample for how to call it using EF.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the critical section:

```
private static readonly object o = new Object();

public SomeModel Get(int id)

    lock (o)
    {
        ...
        credit.Availbale -= 1;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The object you lock on must be static and not of any instance. That way, multiple threads will have to run for the same lock and thus won't interleave execution.

Comment: using a lock in C# when really you want to have locking on the DB side does not seem like the best solution.

Comment: He doesn't talk about workload balancer or multiple nodes in the front-end tier, so I assume he has just one server. Locking in the application is a pretty common practice. He also does not have any performance issues (yet?) so there's no point for early optimisation. Specify your point because it's against all common practice written as you have. Also, no point in downvoting, chill down :)

Comment: This will only harm throughput for the specific method. It will *not* prevent invalid updates from other methods. Databases should be able to serve thousands of concurrent users. Concurrency issues should be addressed by fixing the code, not restricting access. Even a desktop application should *not* use client-side locks when a simple UPDATE would do

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stored procedure to update the database value at the same time as you are getting it.

Comment: Using a stored procedure doesn't help at all if 5 users try to save the same wrong value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But it wouldn't save the wrong value if you run an update script with a return value.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a stored procedure or a raw statement. It's the content that matters. Simply writing a stored procedure with unspecified content won't help